# What convention shows $R_{XYZ} = R_ZR_YR_X$

Tags: matrices

In the book *Introduction to Robotics* by John J. Craig, the explanation of multiplying matrices for fixed-angle rotation is a bit confusing. I understand fixed-angle rotation order $XYZ$ is equal to Euler angle $ZYX$, but I am wondering why the equation is written as following, or what mathematical convention describes this way of writing so I know in the future what it means.

It is described as:

> The derivation of the equivalent rotation matrix,
>   $_B^AR_{XYZ}(\gamma,\beta,\alpha)$ is straight-forward, because
>   all rotations occur about axes of the reference frame; that is,
>   $$
> _B^AR_{XYZ}(\gamma,\beta,\alpha) = R_Z(\alpha)R_Y(\beta)R_X(\gamma)
> $$

Since rotation operations do not commute, the order is important, so I would imagine it should be obvious for a notation to imply it is multiplied in reverse order.

Comment: @OnceUponACrinoid I am asking if there is a convention for why the order is then written backwords.  Reading right to left or left to right is the same, since it is still the matrix Rx*Ry*Rz not Rz*Ry*Rx, and since ABC = A(BC), the order of reading is irrelevant.  Maybe the answer is just 'how to think about it', but i was looking if there was a specific explanation

Comment: Well, when describing Euler rotations, it says Rx'y'z' = Rx*Ry*Rz , and subsequent operations are added to the right side, in both cases (so if you rotate first, then translate based on the rotation, translation is appended to right side)